# .NET service that handles import and export (integration)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, design-patterns, integration

I've been searching google for some tips regarding design patterns when building an integration engine.

I have a SQL Server that holds all the data I want to export (this is also where I will insert the data I import). I have a service that will execute commands based on time-intervals etc. Though one thing I really struggle with is the way to handle the data-process in the software.

For instance, in an export program I made I had a structure similar this

```
// Entity order
public class Order {
    int OrderID { get; set; }
    string OrderNo { get; set; }

    // One order can include loads of registrations
    // A registration can only have a reference to one order
    // Basically a mirror of the database
    List<Registration> RegistrationList { get; set; }
}

// Entity registration
public class Registration {
    int RegistrationID { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    // Some more variables
}

// Controller(?) 
public class OrderController : IControlOrder
{
    private IControlRegistrations _registrationController;
    public OrderController()
    {
        this._registrationController = new RegistrationController();
    }

    public List<Order> get() {
        List<Order> orderList = new List<Order>();
        // Query database
        foreach(...) {
            // Short example
            Order order = new Order();
            order.OrderNo = ...
            order.OrderID = ...
            order.RegistrationList = _registrationController.getRegistrationsBasedOnOrder(order);
        }
        // Iterate through every row
        // Create a new Order-object per iterate
        return orderList;
    }

    public void updateOrder(Order order) {
        // Update the order in the database (set exported-flag)
    }
}

public RegistrationController : IControlRegistrations
{
    public List<Registration> getRegistrationsBasedOnOrder(Order order)
    {
        List<Registration> list = new List<Registration>();
        // Query DB based on OrderID

        return list;
    }

    public void update(Registration registration)
    {
        // Update the registration in the database
    }
}

// Output
public class Output 
{
    private IControlOrder _controller;
    public Output(IControlOrder controller)
    {
        this._controller = controller;
    }

    public void export()
    {
        // Build XML
        // ... Example
        //
        //<Orders>
        //   <Order>
        //      <OrderNo>KF322</OrderNo>
        //      <RegistrationList>
        //         <!-- All the registrations with a reference to this order -->   
        //      </RegistrationList>   
        //   </Order>
        //   <Order>
        //      <OrderNo>KF323</OrderNo>
        //      <RegistrationList>
        //         <!-- All the registrations with a reference to this order -->   
        //      </RegistrationList> 
        //   </Order>
        //</Orders>


        foreach(Order order in _controller.get())
        {
             // Create the order info in the XML, then create registrations
             foreach(Registration reg in order.RegistrationList)
             {
                 // Create the registration list in the XML
             }     
        }
        // Save the file to a network drive.
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure I violate every rule of design patterns there is. Eventually my code gets cluttered and the responsibility of each layer(not sure if I can call it layers) gets a messed up. For instance if an order also has a one-to-many relationship to descriptions and addresses the `OrderController` class gets incredibly cluttered. In my next project I am also going to implement imports, and I wont just be exporting orders but also other master data like that. So I believe I will have to be smart with the interfaces, help classes etc. I will also have to validate all the data I retrieve from both the DB and the integrated program before I output a file or insert it into the DB.

Do any of you know of a good design pattern (just a theory to follow) for an integration engine? The question might not be constructive but the small-house design I use will not be sufficient when the program will be tens of times bigger.

Any help is greatly appreciated :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look on Command-Query Segregation. Basically this boils down to few concepts:

- Commands for writing, queries for reading. Imports are via commands, exports via queries.
- A single command/query deals with only one type of import/export

So to save data from user you'll get file/data in controller and pass that into a command that deals with this type of data. For export you execute query in the controller and query will extract data from DB and format appropriately.

Sometimes if you extract data into XLS or other format you may want to introduce a separate renderer. This way your concerns are separated - query only extracts data, renderer converts that data into required format. This way you can extract data into different formats by only adding new renderers.

Same goes for commands - part of the command can be a parser that parses incoming data into class instance and then command will save that into DB.

You can check out examples and more CQRS details here:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/555855/Introduction-to-CQRS
  http://www.headcrash.us/blog/2011/09/10-command-query-responsibility-segregation-cqrs-examples-in-c/

Comment: I will check that out tomorrow! Sounds like a nice way to have defined responsibilites, and it will probably make the code more understandable as well! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No problem. We have used services and all-round functionality classes, but when you cross the line of 30 controllers, things become messy with that. After moving to CQRS - everything is clear as day: class does one thing and one thing only. You can check out my little app where I use CQRS https://github.com/trailmax/Amv.Reporting but for DB I use Raven DB, rather than EF

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look that bad. There are two naming issues, specifically your controllers are not controllers but **repositories** and your output class is a **service** (so that `OutputService` would be a better name).

Layering is ok. You have a domain model somewhere deep. Then you have repository in upper layer and above it you have your services. If you follow simple convention where repository class names end with `Repository` (`OrderRepository`) and services are `..Service` and you put each layer in a separate assembly and allow upper layer assembly only reference lower layer assemblies, then you will clean up much of your confusion.

My idea would be to not to write your model classes and repositories by hand. This doesn't make much sense as there are a lot of pitfalls. Instead, reverse engineer your model out of the database using Entity Framework reverse engineer code first option and then, instead of creating repositories by hand use Entity Framework instead. The only layer to create by hand is then the service layer where you implement specific business processes.

Comment: It's pretty cool how much more it makes sense as soon as you just change the "minor details" like terminology. EF kind of confuses me since its just like a magic box to me, probably because I havent used it myself, just seen some production code using it. One more thing that comes to mind is the validation of the model data I insert into the model. However I believe I will work that out sometime :) Is this design model names anything specific? Thanks for the help as well, just the terminology change makes it understandable!

Comment: Im sorry to bother you again, I have decided to go for this pattern with the naming convention you presented. If I take above as an example and I want to create two outputs the before mentioned XML and a web service connection,  and one report(what did I really export). Should IOutputService be an abstract class with a defined report method and an abstract Export-method? What design do you suggest for that particular purpose? :)

Comment: @Alex07: sounds like a good, self-contained question for a code review http://codereview.stackexchange.com